# Changing the color of one label changes also the color of the other label in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, label

This is a quite silly question but I can not find a way to make it work. Its related with the visualisation of my nodes and their labels in the neo4j server.
I have created a small number of nodes with two labels. The first one is called: PseudoNode and the second one: RealNode.
When I try to change the color of one label the visualisation rule applies also to the nodes which belong to the second label. Here is an image:
Why this happens?

[image]

Comment: You can reset the stylesheet by going to the stylesheet editor and clicking the fire-extinguisher button, then it should work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this before.  I think it's a bug in the web console.  If you click on `View stylesheet` you can download the stylesheet and edit it locally and then upload it again by dragging it to the place where it says to drag it.  Often I just clear out the stylesheet except for the first few about node/relationship.